# Add files generated by target build to other cmake target

Tags: c++, cmake

My CMake project has a layout like this:

- projectA -> generates target `targetA` which is an executable that generates many files when invoked (I dont know how many or their name before executing it)
- projectB -> adds a custom command that invokes `targetA` which ends up generating all the C++ files it does. Since this is a custom command this happens when building `projectB` and not when generating it.

Now the build of `projectB` should also include building all the files that were generated while invoking the executable built from `projectA`. Is this possible? With protobuffer files it was no problem because I know before what files there are and what their generated name will be, so I can include them at generation time even though they are effectively generated at build time. However in my case I only know the directory all the generated files will be in (and a pattern), but not what files exactly.

Comment: "Is this possible?" - No, you need to specify all files for compile at configuration (generating) stage. You may build `projectA` with `execute_process`, this would allow you to generate files also with `execute_process` and then collect source files with `file(GLOB)`.

Comment: Ahh, too bad, but I can create a tiny java file that is capable of determining all the generated files, and since I already need a JDK for another part of the application this wont be an issue :)